# How to handle default value for a templated functor

Tags: c++, templates, functor

Given a function like this:

```
template<typename functor>
void foo(functor const& f)
{
    if (f)
        f(1, 2);
}
```

I want to be able to assign a default value where `f` can be set to something similar to `NULL`. Also, it would be possible sufficient to make a bogus call to an empty function. Is there anything I can use (from the standard or `boost`-library) without creating such a thing by myself?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? So you want to call `foo` in two ways: `foo(some_functor);` and `foo();` and in the latter case you want `foo();` to do nothing. But why call `foo();` in the first place?

Answer (score 11):

Use an empty functor and use as default template parameter. You can't use something like NULL because you have no pointer:

```
class X
{
    void operator()(...) {}
};

template <typename functor = X>
void foo(functor const& f = X())
{
    f(...);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a default function argument, too: `foo(functor const & f = X())`.

Comment: I'd assume you mean `template <typename functor = X> foo(functor const & f = functor())`. That also allows `foo<void(*)()>()`.

Comment: yes @KerrekSB, you are right. I get confused with class template parameters. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the need for default argument. If you are sometimes not going to pass anything, and the functor doesn't do anything, why call `foo` in the first place?

Comment: @jcalvosa - Default template arguments are only allowed on a class template.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: It seems this has changed in C++11.

Comment: @UncleBens - Indeed it has changed in C++11. But I'm still using C++03.

Comment: I would be nice to get rid of `class X` by using empty lambda expression (starting from C++11), but seems like it would be possible only starting from C++20.

Comment: @ArtemPisarenko I am using c++20. How would you do this?

Comment: @Baruch It was too long time ago. I've tried to remember, but found a way to achieve same even with C++11: https://newbedev.com/default-argument-for-a-functor-in-a-templated-parameter . Thus, code snippet above can be modified in this way: https://pastebin.com/rPXQcAnv

Answer (score 3):

Either write an overload that takes and does nothing, or pass a no-op functor to `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to create an overload that takes no argument:

```
template<typename functor>
void foo()
{
}
```

If the default action depends on the template-parameter, you will have to provide it explicitly though, since there is nothing from which the compiler could deduce it. If not, then you don't even need to make it a template.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to use overloaded functions. It seems to be using a self-written "nop-class" is the best solution.

```
struct nop
{
    void operator()(...) const volatile {}
};

template<typename functor> 
void foo(functor const& f = functor()) 
{
    f(1, 2);
}

int main()
{
    foo<nop>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the variadic member function of `nop` cannot be used if in an instantiation you pass any non-trivially-copyable type for `...`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this as a drop-in no-op for cases where I expect a functor that does not return any value.

```
struct VoidNoOp {
    void operator()() const { }
    template<class A>
    void operator()(A a) const { (void)(a); }
    template<class A, class B>
    void operator()(A a, B b) const { (void)(a); (void)(b); }
    template<class A, class B, class C>
    void operator()(A a, B b, C c) const { (void)(a); (void)(b); (void)(c); }
};
```

Here is a C++11 variation for arbitrary numbers of parameters:

```
struct VoidNoOp {
    void operator()() const { };
    template<typename P1, typename... Params>
    void operator()(P1 p1, Params... parameters) {
        (void)(p1);             // we do this just to remove warnings -- requires the recursion
        operator()(parameters...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `functor` is a type determined by the caller, so it may not have a default constructor, or any other functionality you rely upon to build the default value.

So, can you use an overloaded function?

```
template<typename functor>
void foo(functor const& f)
{
       f(1, 2);
}

template<typename functor>
void foo()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function wrapper that can store NULL at runtime, is `std::function (C++11)` or `boost::function`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <cstdio>

void foo(std::function<void(int, int)> f)
{
    if (f) {
       f(1, 2);
    }
}

void print(int a, int b) { std::printf("%d %d\n", a, b); }

int main()
{
   foo(0);
   foo(print);
}
```

Comment: Using a function wrapper would be functionally adequate, but the performance penalty is not reasonable. Thanks anyway.